# Unity Collider - OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i m begginer with Unity, i started a little project and i m using a framework for inventrory.

I m trying to make a safe zone in my game. My safe zone have a collider with trigger "on".

If my player enter in the safe zone , i just want to send a message.
My problem is when the player enter, i cant get the name of the player, it give me "_TriggerHandler" as value instead of my player.

Code never enter in the "if", i get the first debug log in console but nothing else. ( p is null ) ( other = _TriggerHandler )

Cant understand why other = _TriggerHandler.

```
using Devdog.General;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SafeZone : MonoBehaviour {

    protected vp_FPPlayerEventHandler m_Player = null;
    protected bool safe;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        m_Player = GameObject.Find("Gringan").GetComponent<vp_FPPlayerEventHandler>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
   /// registers this component with the event handler (if any)
   /// </summary>
   protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Register(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// unregisters this component from the event handler (if any)
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Unregister(this);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var p = other.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        print("Collision detected with trigger object " + other.name + " p= " + p);
        if (p != null)
        {
            print("Collision detected with trigger object PLAYER " + other.name);
            safe = true;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        var p = other.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        if (p != null)
        {
            print("Still colliding with trigger object PLAYER " + other.name);
            safe = true;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        var p = other.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        if (p != null)
        {
            print(gameObject.name + " and trigger object PLAYER " + other.name + " are no longer colliding");
            safe = false;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }
}
```

Console message :

-->

Collision detected with trigger object _TriggerHandler p=
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
SafeZone:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/My Assets/Scripts/SafeZone.cs:44)

I want to know if anyone knows what can make this happens ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this means the Collider that triggered the function is NOT on the same transform as the Player. E.g. if your character has colliders on his legs and triggers this, the `other` object will be the leg, not the character itself. You have to find the Player component somewhere on the parent transform. P.s. `other.attachedrigidbody` may be a bit of help if the Player component and Rigidbody are attached to the same transform

Comment: Thanks for your infos. I will look at this. I use UFPS , my colliders are far in hierarchy. I tryed right now with other.attachedrigidbody but same result :( Collision detected with trigger object _TriggerHandler p=   So P is null. Any idea how i do ?

Comment: find where is the Player in the hierarchy relative to _TriggerHandler. If it's attached to the parent of _TriggerHandler then in your code you'll have to get it like this: `other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>();` or use `.parent.parent` to climb 2 transforms up in hierarchy. Or use `GetComponentInChildren<Player>()` if it's attached to a child transform somewhere below `_TriggerHandler`

Comment: thanks so much, it worked. with other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>();

Comment: Ok it work, but i have a error. 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SafeZone.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/My Assets/Scripts/SafeZone.cs:45)
It work because i have the name of the player but in console this error repeat a lot of time. I have read about null exception. I have to test if its null before using the variable. Thats what i do on line 47. (if p != null ) but the error occurs on line 45 when i do : player = other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>(). I dont understand why.

Comment: That means your statement in start is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131592/discussion-between-mad-mask-and-nika-kasradze).

Comment: Are you able to come on chat ? code works but i still have the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it work by using `other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>();` like Nika Kasradze said and then I had to test if the player was null before doing anything else :).

Thanks for your help !

```
using Devdog.General;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SafeZone : MonoBehaviour {

    protected vp_FPPlayerEventHandler m_Player = null;
    protected bool safe;
    protected Player player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (m_Player == null)
        {
            m_Player = GameObject.Find("Gringan").GetComponent<vp_FPPlayerEventHandler>();
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// registers this component with the event handler (if any)
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Register(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// unregisters this component from the event handler (if any)
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void OnDisable()
    {
        if (m_Player != null)
            m_Player.Unregister(this);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (player == null)
        {
            player = other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        }

        if (player != null)
        {
            print("Collision detected with trigger object "  + player.name);
            safe = true;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }

    /*void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
       if (player == null)
        {
            player = other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        }

        if (p != null)
        {
            print("Still colliding with trigger object PLAYER " + p.name);
            safe = true;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }*/

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (player == null)
        {
            player = other.transform.parent.GetComponent<Player>(); // Player is in Devdog.General;
        }

        if (player != null)
        {
            print(gameObject.name + " and trigger object PLAYER " + player.name + " are no longer colliding");
            safe = false;
            m_Player.PlayerIsSafe.Send(safe);
        }
    }
}
```