# How to check if object is inside terrain area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a  plane and when i click on the plane it's spawning objects on the plane area and on the terrain ground.

but i want to do that if the plane or part of it is out of the terrain area that it will disable the spawning part.

This screenshot show the plane above the terrain.

[image: plane above terrain area]

and this screenshot where the plane is out of the terrain area but i can still click on the plane and spawn objects.

[image: plane is outside the terrain area]

This is the spawn objects script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToSpawn;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public CustomPlane plane;
    public GameObject spawnedTerrainObjectsParent;
    public GameObject spawnedPlaneObjectsParent;
    public bool go = false;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float duration;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    public bool isParent = true;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;

    private float planeWidth;
    private float planeLength;
    private float xPlanePos;
    private float zPlanePos;

    private float yValTerrain;
    private float yValPlane;

    private float randXTerrain;
    private float randZTerrain;

    private float randXPlane;
    private float randZPlane;

    private GameObject cube;

    private Collider terrainCollider;
    void Awake()
    {
        if (terrain != null)
        {
            //Get terrain size
            terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
            terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

            //Get terrain position
            xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
            zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

            terrainCollider = terrain.GetComponent<Collider>();
        }

        if (plane != null)
        {
            planeWidth = plane.width;
            planeLength = plane.length;
            xPlanePos = plane.transform.position.x;
            zPlanePos = plane.transform.position.z;
        }

        if (isParent)
        {
            if(spawnedTerrainObjectsParent == null)
            {
                spawnedTerrainObjectsParent = GameObject.Find("Spawned Terrain Parent");
            }

            if(spawnedPlaneObjectsParent == null)
            {
                spawnedPlaneObjectsParent = GameObject.Find("Spawned Plane Parent");
            }
        }

        Camera.main.transform.position = 
            new Vector3(plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center.x, 635,
            plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center.z);

        if (go)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Generate());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Generate()
    {
        //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            if (terrain != null)
            {
                //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
                randXTerrain = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
                randZTerrain = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
                yValTerrain = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randXTerrain, 0, randZTerrain));
                yValTerrain = yValTerrain + yOffset;

                GameObject objInstanceTerrain = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabToSpawn,
                new Vector3(randXTerrain, yValTerrain, randZTerrain), Quaternion.identity);

                objInstanceTerrain.name = "Terrain Spawned";

                if (isParent)
                {
                    objInstanceTerrain.transform.parent = spawnedTerrainObjectsParent.transform;
                }
            }

            if (plane != null)
            {
                randXPlane = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xPlanePos, xPlanePos + planeWidth);
                randZPlane = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zPlanePos, zPlanePos + planeLength);
                yValPlane = 0;
                yValPlane = yValPlane + yOffset;

                GameObject objInstancePlane = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabToSpawn,
                new Vector3(randXPlane, yValPlane, randZPlane), Quaternion.identity);

                objInstancePlane.name = "Plane Spawned";

                if (isParent)
                {
                    objInstancePlane.transform.parent = spawnedPlaneObjectsParent.transform;
                }
            }

            if (duration > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        SpawnThroughPlane();
    }
    public void SpawnThroughPlane()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (plane.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            {
                cube = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);
                cube.transform.position = hit.point;

                float heightFromTerrain = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(hit.point);
                var posy = hit.point.y;
                posy -= heightFromTerrain;
                var newpos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y - posy, hit.point.z);
                Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, newpos, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try box collider with the set trigger on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Collider - OnTriggerEnter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331296/unity-collider-ontriggerenter)